# Default parameters with generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Consider the last example of generics from the TypeScript Docs:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

If I wanted to make `Lion` the default value for `createInstance()` how would I do this?

For example:

```
class Animal {
  numLegs: number = 0;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
  keeper = "zookeeper";
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A = Lion): A { // error!
// -------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  'Lion' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be 
// instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.
  return new c();
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0BcoBmBDANpApgFCLaaSSgBCeeA0tQA56ygDeBooAFqQLKkDWaAEYB7EdjyYAdqAC8oOAFc8AbgIBfAkRJlQALTF08jZmw5TMAWzzRMAczQwEUu3NAAid2s3bS5AIJS8JY4rOygUoqWADJ4dpBokZZCTG4ADN5axH6U1KB4AB7QeFIAJgFBIdhhHPwMTGhUtPXM8lJ4AO65zcZMABQAlJm+utHwIjKFxWUVwaFmoHW9sGgGIkYmbu1daxv9Qxpa6IpSyOMyiLCSxQCSUjDSiHgAPP75RSXloIFz2AB8fUQiU6oEGcj+3zcYwmAzQbwWV2gilgMm2oEQg2Gl2ueDuD1OeD60KkAwAdEsTKSLNZbHY1NjMLd7rYCX0mmSKUxSdxIHxIPw1AQQKAAPLMeDoCIiaCceAuUDwcj0Px4UqgRT4UClPBYRTYaCgABuOGUoBEkuJRCujNxzMehLJSVi8TUQA)

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no way to do this with compiler-verified type safety.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315) for the relevant feature request.  Right now all the approaches involve working around this limitation.

---

You could use [a generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that a lack of inference for `A` implies that `A` is `Lion`, and that it's okay to make that assumption:

```
function createInstanceAssert<A extends Animal = Lion>(c: new () => A = Lion as any) {
  return new c();
}
```

This will work as desired in your use cases, I think:

```
createInstanceAssert(Lion).keeper.nametag;
createInstanceAssert(Bee).keeper.hasMask;
createInstanceAssert().keeper.nametag;
```

Although there is the possibility of someone manually specifying the generic parameter and causing trouble:

```
createInstanceAssert<Bee>().keeper.hasMask.valueOf(); // compiles, but error at runtime
// ---------------> ~~~~~ don't do this, okay?
```

That's probably not likely, but you should be aware of it.

---

If you really want to prevent misuse you could use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to distinguish the two separate use cases:

```
function createInstanceOverload<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A;
function createInstanceOverload(): Lion;
function createInstanceOverload(c: new () => Animal = Lion) {
  return new c();
}
```

You can basically call that with a parameter, in which case it is generic and `A` is inferred, or you can call it with no parameter, in which case it is *not* generic, and a `Lion` comes out:

```
createInstanceOverload(Lion).keeper.nametag;
createInstanceOverload(Bee).keeper.hasMask;
createInstanceOverload().keeper.nametag;
```

Since there is no generic zero-arg call signature, the following is no longer possible without a big compiler error:

```
createInstanceOverload<Bee>().keeper.hasMask.valueOf(); // error at compile time
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0BcoBmBDANpApgFCLaaSSgBCeeA0tQA56ygDeBooAFqQLKkDWaAEYB7EdjyYAdqAC8oOAFc8AbgIBfAkRJlQALTF08jZmw5TMAWzzRMAczQwEUu3NAAid2s3bS5AIJS8JY4rOygUoqWADJ4dpBokZZCTG4ADN5axH6U1KB4AB7QeFIAJgFBIdhhHPwMTGhUtPXM8lJ4AO65zcZMABQAlJm+utHwIjKFxWUVwaFmoHW9sGgGIkYmbu1daxv9QxrsWuiKUsjjMoiwksUAklIw0oh4-mRM0AA8-vlFJeWggTm1XkYwmAD4+ohEp1QIM5GCAW5QTJSKBpABPAY1UDXaCKWAybagRCDYZXG54e6PM4vN6waB9ZEDAB0SxMzIs1lsdjU5Mwdwethpr3w9L6TRZbKYzO4kD4kH4vOu-MpgqetNFDMlLQ5Vhs9jURGVAupzxF7w+TQh2uWMt4AmZADccMoAPLoUmgED5WCwETMfk407QYKEb0AWkjUejMYRAD8EwnQKUJgByaDJkQKTjwSAAGlAIn4mHRAH4tAQTmcQxNicbVaa8K7HUxsCJMKUvj9pv9AVUIVCIjC4bIEf4Bmh-Goq+da3yTULns3W+3SoM0Mjp6dZ5d61TF02W7A2x3IdCuiOx5VQiCLliFrj8YSYSSDj55w2D8vj6vGXfWTqnL6jyRoUvu6rfiea4SgBtqyvKiqgSq4E0pBv42uyQHcoaH4oUuR5QZa1DWrB7LwQ6zrYG6HpDF6YBMH6AYZogIiWPQ8ASAooYEEAA)