# Typscript generic function with default parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function like below that accepts a flag and value parameters. I want to set the default value of the flag to false, but the TS compiler complains that `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

```js
function myFunc<T extends boolean = false>(
  flag: T = false,
  value: T extends true ? Array<string> : string
) {
  // function body
}
```

---

A more accurate example would be something like:

```js
interface ArgType<T extends boolean> {
  flag: T,
  value: T extends true ? Array<string> : string
}

function myFunc<T extends boolean>({
  flag,
  value
}: ArgType<T>) {
  // function body
}
```

Comment: What is the point of having `flag` be "optional" (which is what default function values enable) while having `value` be required?  You can't call `myFunc("")` or `myFunc(, "")`; you'd have to call `myFunc(undefined, "")`, which is more annoying than `myFunc(false, "")`.  So I must be missing something.  Optional parameters really belong *after* all required parameters.  

Comment: Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359529/2887218) to the question this duplicates; if I translate the code there to this question I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLLaam).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after writing this question I realized I could solve this by casting the default value as T, like this:

```js
interface ArgType<T extends boolean> {
  flag: T,
  value: T extends true ? Array<string> : string
}

function myFunc<T extends boolean>({
  flag = false as T,
  value
}: ArgType<T>) {
  // function body
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to see when someone calls `myFunc(undefined, ["oops"]);` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zY2N)?

Comment: That's a good callout. In my exact case I'm using a single argument that is itself generically typed using `T`, so that's not an issue. But you're right, the issue in this example still stands