# How to type return value as boolean|typeof param

Tags: typescript

Given

```
function toBool(str: string|boolean|number|any[], def:any=undefined): boolean|typeof def {
    return true;
}

const x = toBool('true',false);
```

Mousing over `x` shows its of type `any`. But in this scenario, it should be a boolean because I've specified `def`.

Likewise, if I do

```
const y = toBool('true','fallback');  // y should be boolean|string (or boolean|"fallback" would also be fine)
const z = toBool('true');  // z should be boolean|undefined
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=71&pln=3&pc=79#code/LAKFDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aACeyBCzkBsAKAZ3gCcAuNE0xaAcwB8AjXPAUwENoHpIBbJm1IMuATwDaAXQA0aACZtw5MQF4YC8LTZyAlJRb5O3eKIAObZOHmK0Ab1BpHaUm3iRS6MpDYBuUAF9QUFhUEjQADzQVDGxWAgByLzZ46XAOPCI2HR8gA)

How can I achieve this?

I've also tried this:

```
function toBool<TDefault>(str: string|boolean|number|any[], def:TDefault=undefined): boolean|TDefault
```

But that gives an error,

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TDefault'.
> 'TDefault' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.

Comment: See e.g. [default-parameters-with-generics-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359115/default-parameters-with-generics-in-typescript), in case the default doesn't happen to luckily be `undefined`, and be expressible by an optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic `T` with a default type of `undefined`, and make the default value an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=10&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOAhOcA2iA8AVRAXkXABMBTYGMc0gPgAoAoRRANwENMRyAuRAM5QATtQDmiAD6IARhkzkOSaWBABbGeWFTESgJ4BtALoAaFogrAOITFABqXHgH5+eMwEp+crIuWICAN7mwuRQIMJIIjwA3EwAvkxMEAhCiAAeRMho8gwA5FHkuSaIVpgC5O7RiAD01bLyvkkpUIh6mSjoWHkFRbmlmDIcEADWuZU1dd4KSjoARP2DI7NNYKkAXu3ZXfnCPGNVtfU+M9JklNS0TEA)

```ts
function toBool <T = undefined>(
  value: string | boolean | number | any[],
  defaultValue?: T,
): boolean | T {
  return true;
}

const x = toBool('true', false); // boolean
const y = toBool('true','fallback'); // boolean | "fallback"
const z = toBool('true'); // boolean | undefined
```

Comment: Ahah. I think there's one more caveat that you have to do `as T` inside the method body when attempting to return the `defaultValue`; https://go.mpen.ca/395pq